# Textarea with padding vertical-align top next to label

Tags: css

When I add padding to my textarea then vertical-align top does not work.

Browser: Firefox

CSS:

```
.form-aligned textarea-label {
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 120px;
    text-align: left;
}

textarea {
    padding: 6px 12px;
}
```

I am looking for a result like this but with padding added to textarea:

[image]

It drives me crazy it should be simple :-)

Comment: Provide HTML, I can't reproduce the issue [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8cz2epwc/)

Comment: why dont use margin.
or you can use padding-left or right.

Comment: Is margin better to use for this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use divs to separate the label from the textarea.

```
<div style="float:left;">
<label>Incident: </label>
</div>
<div style="float:left;">
<textarea id="txtIncident"></textarea>
</div>

label {
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 120px;
    text-align: left;
}

textarea {
    padding: 6px 12px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7z0uwtLu/

Comment: Thanks for this quick response, i found out if i remove rows and cols attribute from my textarea then it also works without divs. My mistake I forgot to mention this in the css code :-)